# Advice on how to fix Workbench Moderation error messages

Tags: 7, workbench

(n00b drupal person)

I seem to be suffering the problems described in https://drupal.org/node/1966908 and https://drupal.org/node/1966920.

Basically I have installed the following:

```
drupal-7.26.tar.gz
media-7.x-1.4.tar.gz
views-7.x-3.7.tar.gz
ctools-7.x-1.3.tar.gz
workbench-7.x-1.2.tar.gz
workbench_access-7.x-1.2.tar.gz
workbench_media-7.x-1.1.tar.gz
workbench_moderation-7.x-1.3.tar.gz
```

It all seems to be configured OK, but when I switch to My Workbench -> Create Content I get the following warning/error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: #contextual_links in
>   contextual_pre_render_links() (line 140 of
>   /home/apache/drupal-7.26/modules/contextual/contextual.module).
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   contextual_pre_render_links() (line 140 of
>   /home/apache/drupal-7.26/modules/contextual/contextual.module).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: #contextual_links in
>   contextual_pre_render_links() (line 140 of
>   /home/apache/drupal-7.26/modules/contextual/contextual.module).
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   contextual_pre_render_links() (line 140 of
>   /home/apache/drupal-7.26/modules/contextual/contextual.module).
>
> Notice: Undefined index: #contextual_links in
>   contextual_pre_render_links() (line 140 of
>   /home/apache/drupal-7.26/modules/contextual/contextual.module).
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   contextual_pre_render_links() (line 140 of
>   /home/apache/drupal-7.26/modules/contextual/contextual.module).

Would very much appreciate some help with:

1. Confirmation I've got the right bugs
2. Some advice on fixing it... should really be using `git patch` rather than installing the updated modules to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I found a workaround, which is good enough for the timebeing... enable Views UI modules - https://drupal.org/comment/6971496#comment-6971496

Answer (score 0):

certainly enabling views UI solve the problem but a more suitable solution is provided in this patch [[#1727284-1]](https://www.drupal.org/files/1727284-workbench-contextual.patch)

Answer (score 0):

Enable Views UI and error goes away.